# removing duplicate ids from array of arrays from a specific index

Tags: javascript

I want to remove duplicate ids from `pureIDs[2]`. so the index here is `2`. the only condition is the arrays I want to search for duplicates are the ones with lower indices so I want to search 0 and 1.

If we want to `pureIDs[3]` then we should search 0 , 1 , 2 (the lower indices)

My attempt is a total failure Here:

The desired result is : `[22, 9]` here.

```js
const pureIDs = [
   [0, 1, 23, 5, 11],
   [2, 15, 23, 25, 10],
   [2, 10, 22, 9, 11], // Modify this index (2)
   [20, 24],
 
 ];
 // I give the index here
 const ids = getModifiedIDs(pureIDs[2], 2);
 
 console.log(ids); // This should result in : [22, 9]
 
 function getModifiedIDs(ids, from) {
   let sets = [];
   for(let b = from - 1; b > -1; b--){
       console.log(b)
       set = ids.filter((el) => {
       return !pureIDs[b].includes(el);
       });
       sets.push(set)
       
      
   }
   
    return sets; 
        
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a slight modification gives you the result needed.

Change your function to:

```
function getModifiedIDs(ids, from) {
    const set = ids.filter((el) => {
        for(let b = from - 1; b > -1; b--){
            if (pureIDs[b].includes(el)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
   
    return set; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Build a set from the arrays with deletable indexes. Than you get with [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Set#has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) your result.

```js
function  getModifiedIDs(ids, from)  {
    let dels = [];
    for (i=0; i<from-1; i++)
        dels = dels.concat(pureIDs[i]);

    let delSet = new Set(dels);

    return ids.filter(id => !delSet.has(id) );
}


const pureIDs = [
   [0, 1, 23, 5, 11],
   [2, 15, 23, 25, 10],
   [2, 10, 22, 9, 11], // Modify this index (2)
   [20, 24],
  ];
 
console.log(getModifiedIDs(pureIDs[2], 3));
```